# How to get a list all the "aliases" of a file (including of type directory) efficiently?

Tags: files, mount, filenames, symlink, hard-link

How can one get the list of all the aliases of a file (including of type directory) efficiently, given that a file:

1. may have multiple hard links, multipe soft links, multi-level soft links
2. may be present under a directory which is mounted at another location in the same filesystem
3. may be present under a directory that has link(s) pointing to it; again the links having features mentioned in 1

Could a possible solution be using inodes?

Comment: GNU `find` has the `-samefile` option, but `find /` is hardly efficient as it has to basically traverse the entire filesystem.

Comment: I suppose there might be a way to find the other hard links in *some* file system formats, but if you want soft links as well then I'm afraid it's brute force or nothing.

Comment: See also [How do I see what symlinks exist for a given directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/how-do-i-see-what-symlinks-exist-for-a-given-directory) — that doesn't deal with multi-level symlinks, but the basic principle is the same (no, there's no method that doesn't involve an exhaustive search).

Answer (score 1):

Hard links can be identified by comparing both the inode number *and* the device number (two different mounted file systems may each have a file with the same inode number, but they will have different device numbers). You can read the device/inode manually with `stat $file`, or `find` can do it for you with `-samefile`. You can make searching for hard links more efficient by searching only within the same device:

```
find $fsroot/. -mount -samefile $myfile
```

Soft links are harder as they can be located anywhere. You need to dereference them to identify the inode/device. You can do this manually with `stat -L` or automatically with `find -L`:

```
find -L / -samefile $myfile
```

Note that this will *also* find hard links. I don't think `find` has an easy way to search for only soft links that point to a specific inode.

It might be that some file-systems can tell you this information more efficiently, but I think the in the general case you need to scan every file.