# Removing file and its sym links

Tags: command-line, symlink, rm

If I create a file and symlink to it e.g

```
touch "example"
ln -s "example" "link_example"
```

and use

```
rm example
```

the symlink is still there. How can I delete file and all symlinks that points to that file with it?

Comment: Closely related: [How do I see what symlinks exist for a given directory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/how-do-i-see-what-symlinks-exist-for-a-given-directory)

Answer (score 7):

There's no link from a file to symlinks that point to it, so there's no direct way of considering `example` and finding `link_example` which links to it. So deleting symlinks pointing to a file along with the file involves finding all the symlinks first.

You don't specify what system you're using, but if you have [GNU `find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/), you can delete a file and its links with

```
find -L / -samefile example -delete
```

You might want to run

```
find -L / -samefile example
```

first to list what will be deleted.

This instructs `find` to follow symlinks (`-L`), start from `/`, and report any file which resolves to the same inode as `example` — so this will match hard and soft links to `example` as well as `example` itself.

Alternatively, using only [POSIX `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), you can delete `example` and then look for broken symlinks:

```
rm example
find -L / -type l
```

If you're sure all the results should be deleted:

```
find -L / -type l -exec rm {} +
```

will delete all the broken symlinks (in directories you can write to).