# How to find all symbolic links pointing to any file/directory inside a given directory

Tags: symlink

[On this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3710/how-do-i-see-what-symlinks-exist-for-a-given-directory) or [on this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100170/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-there-are-symbolic-links-pointing-to-a-directory) (for example) you will get solutions on how to look for symlinks pointing to a given directory (let's call it `/dir1`), while I am interested to symbolic links possibly pointing to any file/folder inside `/dir1`.

I want to delete such directory but I am not sure that I am safe to do so, as on an other directory (let's call it `/dir2`), I may have symlinks pointing to inner parts of `/dir1`.

Further, I may have created these symlinks using absolute or relative paths. 
My only help is that I know the symlinks I want to check are on a mounted filesystem, on `/dir2`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can find all the symbolic links using:

```
find / -type l
```

you might want to run this as root in order to get to every place on the disc.

You can expand these using `readlink -f` to get the full path of the link and you should be able to `grep` the output against the target directory that you are considering for deletion:

```
find / -type l -exec readlink -f {} + | grep -F /dir2
```

Using `find / -type l -printf '%l\n'` doesn't work as you get relative links like `../tmp/xyz` which might be pointing to your target dir, but are not matched because they are not fully expanded.

Comment: In case of subtree it can be useful to follow symlinks: `find -L /subtree -xtype l -exec readlink -f {} +`

Comment: What does the `+` do here?

Comment: @Liam It tells find that the -exec is finished and that multiple arguments should be passed to the command (`readlink`) at the position of `{}` (you can also finish with `;` (which needs to be escaped in many shells), to invoke the command with a single argument, which is much slower to execute.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, the accepted answer wasn't useful (because it didn't output the link  source). Here is what worked for me.

I worked around it using two `-exec` clauses:

```
find /home/ -type l -exec readlink -nf {} ';' -exec echo " <- {}" ';' | grep "/dir2"
```

Comment: This works, but the arrow (->) is misleading, it should point from right to left (<-).

Comment: Rather than flipping the arrow, this would print the expected output: `find /home/ -type l -printf '%p -> ' -exec readlink -f {} ';' | grep "/dir2"`

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 /dir2/**/*(ND@e['[[ $REPLY:P = /dir1(/*|) ]]'])
```

Broken down:

- `print -rC1`: prints its arguments `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn. Here, the arguments will be those generated from the following glob. Replace with `ls -ld` to get more information about each symlink¹
- `**/`: any level of subdirectories (recursive globbing)
- `*`: file with any name (made of any number of characters, though zsh's `*` like that of most shells will also allow non-characters).
- `(...)`: glob qualifiers to further qualify the matching on other criteria than just the name of the files
- `N`: enable `nullglob` for that one glob (won't fail if there's no match, just pass an empty list to `print` which will print nothing).
- `D`: enable `dotglob`: also consider hidden files.
- `@`: restrict to files of type *symlink*.
- `e['code']`: select files for which the `code` evaluates to true. Inside the `code`, the file being considered is stored in `$REPLY`.
- `$REPLY:P`: gets the absolute and canonical (symlink free) path to the file (similar to what the `realpath()` standard function does).
- `[[ string = pattern ]]` returns true if the string matches the pattern (from ksh).
- `/dir1(/*|)` as a pattern matches on `/dir1` alone or `/dir1/` followed by anything.

---

<sup>¹ with the caveat that if there's not matching file, that will list the current working directory. With `ls`, it would be better to remove the `N` glob qualifier</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your circumstances, you could delete the directory, then delete any resultant invalid symlinks with the following:

```
find -xtype l -delete
```

The xtype test returns 'l' if the symlink is broken.